# iCloud Drive on file selection not working

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, icloud

We are trying to test uploading files from iCloud files but it seems like the iCloud is not working on the simulator.

It only shows blank, where in fact there are files on iCloud. Then after some time of waiting then file selection shows Turn On iCloud Drive where in fact it was already turned on.

[image]
[image]
[image]

iPhone 11
XCode 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud is only supported on xcode 12.x with IOS 14.X though iCloud is available on xcode 11 but it is not well implemented I guess,

If you are using Catalina, you can use xcode 12.4, more to this version will only supports Bigsure.